# I need help to understand this grammar あのときこうしていればということば

Tags: grammar

> あのときこうしていればということば

I don't know how to break this sentence down. All I know in it is あのとき = that time

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 日々心によぎる、あの時こうしていればという言葉

日々心によぎる - Everyday, it has been crossing my mind
「あのとき、こうしていれば」 - 'what if I had done this at that time'
という言葉 - the words

Put these in the normal order.
「あのときこうしていれば」という言葉が日々私の心をよぎる
The phrase: 'what if I had done this at that moment' has been crossing my mind everyday over and over.